# Java: but you need to make each JVM, don't you?

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn Java (as the second language from Python), but I can't understand the very first point of it. From my understanding, it says:

"Making **each kind of compiler (e.g. of C/C++) to each kind of CPU** is too much of a hassle. Java, on the other hand, works universally once JVM is installed, because its intermediate code is interpreted by JVM, rather than making a specific native code."

...but don't you need to implement **each kind of JVM to each kind of CPU?** Is this really an advantage of Java over C/C++?

I think there's a duplicate about this in SO or elsewhere on the internet, but sorry, I couldn't think up any good search word.

Comment: Yes, but that's not our problem.

Comment: It is also the same for Python, which has a VM written for different platforms too.

Comment: Someone only makes each JVM once. If you write in C you need to compile for each platform each and every time.

Comment: You also need to make a C/C++ compiler AND a linker "each and every time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes someone need to implement each kind of JVM to each kind of CPU? And if this JVM is going to be used, it will also contain a jit compiler, so not much benefit compared to just writing a compiler.

But it might be talking about using the jvm as a target for your own compiled language.

Imagine this: You want to make your own language. Lets call it MyLanguage. Normally **you** would have to write a compiler, for each cpu, and lots of support code for each operation system you want to support.

But if you just write one compiler which compiles MyLanguage  to java bytecode, then the user can run the java byte code on a JVM.

Your language can then be used on any processor/operation system currently supported by a JVM. And you only had to write one compiler.

This is for example what the developers of Scala did.

Answer (score 5):

*each kind of JVM to each kind of CPU* is implemented by folks from oracle and other JVM vendors: in case of C/C++ you have to compile YOUR application code for each CPU/OS

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *someone* has to make a JVM to be able to run on different platforms, but that someone isn't you.

If you go to the download link for Java https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp you can see there are various JVM builds for Windows, Mac, Linux and Solaris etc

As a programmer, you just have to write your own code and compile it into .class files.  Then it's someone else's problem to provide a JVM to run those class files on a specific machine.